# DS registered EventHandler misses event

Tags: osgi, equinox

I have two `EventHandlers` registered via `DS` (declarative services).
Now, there is another DS service calling `EventAdmin.sendEvent()`.
It happens that only one of the `EventHandlers` receives the event as one of them seems to not be ready when the event is fired.
As a consequence, when the second `EventHandler` becomes available, it is too late as the event is already consumed.
Both `EventHandlers` have `immediate=true` set in the `@Component` annotation.

Is there an "elegant" way to solve this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a timing issue. Not all the consumers are ready when the producer produces. The point of Event Admin is to decouple event producers from consumers. But if you need to make sure all consumers see all events, then you will need to either ensure all consumers are ready to receive before any producer produces, or select another mechanism which can deliver events from the past to newly arriving consumers.

Comment: Thanks, decoupling would have been great here, but remembering past events adds too much complexity to the runtime... I will switch to another solution.